# Storing struct trees on disk

Tags: go, struct

I have the following struct:

```
type Post struct {
  Id    int
  Name  string
  Text  string
  Posts []Post
}
```

To add some data, I do the following:

```
var posts []Post

posts = append(posts, Post{Id: 0, Name: "a", Text: "b"})
posts[0].Posts = append(posts[0].Posts, Post{Id: 1, Name: "c", Text: "d"})

posts = append(posts, Post{Id: 2, Name: "e", Text: "f"})
posts[0].Posts = append(posts[0].Posts, Post{Id: 3, Name: "h", Text: "d"})
```

How can I efficiently store this struct tree on disk? I'm looking for something which can be used without a server (like SQLite). I would like to be able to search for `Id` 2 or 3, returning the entire struct with the `Id` 2 or 3, respectively. Also, I would like to be able to update a single struct, f.e. the one with `Id` 2.

Also, would it be better to use a map, using `Id` as the map's key?

Comment: The recommended solution may depend on factors not mentioned in the question, e.g. how many of these structs you intend to store, may they be read into memory, may there be any limits to length of strings and the depth of the tree?

Comment: @icza those factors aren't really relevant for my use-case, but I'd like to have an efficient solution which is able to store 10 but also 100k structs. The strings can be limited (1024 characters), but it should be configurable. The same applies for the depth of the tree, a maximum depth of 10 is a good example in my use-case.

Comment: @icza after some reflections I noticed that it would be interesting to see what type of different solutions exist depending on those factors.

Comment: Well, SQLite is a good option when you need a database without the database server. It is probably the easiest way to do atomic updates on a set of records. You can also use Gorm relation manager if you want to avoid writing SQL by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Use the encoding/gob put the binary data in a file or get it out again

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Post struct {
    Id    int
    Name  string
    Text  string
    Posts []Post
}

func main() {

    var posts []Post

    posts = append(posts, Post{Id: 0, Name: "a", Text: "b"})
    posts[0].Posts = append(posts[0].Posts, Post{Id: 1, Name: "c", Text: "d"})

    posts = append(posts, Post{Id: 2, Name: "e", Text: "f"})
    posts[0].Posts = append(posts[0].Posts, Post{Id: 3, Name: "h", Text: "d"})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", posts)

    path := "post.gob"

    // write
    out, err1 := os.Create(path)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File write error: %v\n", err1)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    w := bufio.NewWriter(out)
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(w)
    enc.Encode(posts)
    w.Flush()
    out.Close()

    // read
    b := make([]Post, 10)
    in, err2 := os.Open(path)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File read error: %v\n", err2)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    r := bufio.NewReader(in)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(r)
    dec.Decode(&b)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this way I will only be able to get/update the whole contents of `posts`, rather than being able to get/update a single struct.

Comment: You can update a single struct.  But you'll have to load them all, update and then write them all again.  If (for example) you put each of the Post structs in a single file then probably updating would be a little quicker but reading would be slower.  There are half way houses like using sharding (splitting the Post struct list in half or quarter) . All of this sounds like reinventing the database however.  Why not try timing the approach above with 100k records and seeing how it does?

Comment: I will definitively have to do a benchmark on this. I'm just a little bit surprised that there isn't a library for that use-case. But I guess it is that common to store struct trees on disk.